# Webserver with static same host (Amazon)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to build a webserver instance in Amazon that handles both PHP and static requests. Here's my idea ... is it crazy to join varnish + apache + lighttpd ?

Varnish in port 80 handling as reverse proxy.
Apache2 in port 8080 to server PHP files (main requests to web pages) (called by Varnish)
Lighttpd in port 81 to server just static files (called by HTML files)

The domains use to main web page (domain.com) and static content (cdn-domain.com) will pass through the Amazon ELB.

Make all sense ?

Answer (score 1):

no point to use lighttpd.

If you use varnish the static content can be set to be cached and served with varnish. It'll be a lot quicker then lighttpd also.

But yes.. you can do that setup

Comment: will varnish handle static content as good as lighttpd does ? i didn't know that about varnish ... i usually use lighttpd or nginx for static content

Comment: so, do you think it will be better without the lighttpd (webserver just for static content) ?

Comment: varnish will destroy lighttpd serving static content that is in the varnish cache.